# How to use several commands through the pipe as shell script

Tags: bash, shell, firebase, pipe

I am using firebase.

I want to write a shell script that do the following:
Executing two commands:

1. firebase init
2. firebase deploy

The problem is that `firebase init` prompts with several questions.
The first one I want to answer with y for yes and enter afterwards.
Then press the key space to deselect one item and enter to continue.
A few other questions follow.

But I cannot make `firebase init` to accept the first entries I mentioned above.

When I use "echo y | firebase init" it works. But when I add the space key and enter `firebase init` exits without doing what it should.

Is it possible to solve this problem. I am new to shell scripting. I am using Cygwin with Windows 7.

Comment: Look hard at the docs for Firebase's `init`; there's a decent chance there is a way of driving it from the command line without interaction, or that there's a related command that can be used which is non-interactive and designed for use from scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html) the `firebase init` command just creates the file `firebase.json`. Why not do it interactively then just manually generate the JSON later?

Ie if you do it and it generates

```
{
  "firebase": "myfirebase",
  "public": "app",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

then you can just do

```
$ echo $'{\n  "firebase": "myfirebase",\n  "public": "app",\n  "ignore": [\n    "firebase.json",\n    "**/.*",\n    "**/node_modules/**"\n  ]\n}\n' >firebase.json
$ firebase deploy
```

Comment: The newlines in the JSON are unnecessary.

Comment: The newlines in the JSON are harmless.

Comment: It was also cheap with vim: `%s/\n/\\n/g'` so it's harmless and didnt take effort.

Comment: It works. First as answered above a json file must be created with echo. Then the following must be added to the script: firebase deploy -p <project alias>